# ArcGIS field calculator, shorten text

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am new on Python and using Python within ArcGIS and a bit stuck hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I want to remove the 6 last characters if the field is longer than 6 characters.
I'm using the script in the field calculator.

```
def doThis(fld):
    val = 0
    if len(fld) > 6:
        val = fld[len(fld)-6]
    return val
    else:
        val = fld
    return val


Dothis( !Asset_ref!)
```

With the code above I get a SyntaxError: Invalid syntax (line6)

Comment: You haven't used Python string slicing syntax, and you have too many `return` directives (or wrong indent). Hint: "line 6" sometimes means "on line 5, making parse on line 6 invalid"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code you would need to use in the code block:

Pre-logic script:

```
def truncate_string(value):
  if len(value) > 6:
    return value[0:-6]
  else:
    return value
```

Call:

```
truncate_string( !CITY_NAME! )
```

Result:

```
CITY_NAME   ShortName
ABCDEFGHIJKL ABCDEF
Abilene A
Abington    Ab
Ada Ada
Addison A
Adelphi A
Adrian  Adrian
Affton  Affton
Agoura Hills    Agoura
Akron   Akron
Alameda A
Alamo   Alamo
```